# Union and intersection of two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, union, intersection

I'm developing a code where i need to make a union and intersection of two dimensional arrays.

**Code**

```
    System.out.print("True set of  assigned by us\n");
    for (int s = 0 ; s < count ; s++)
    {
        for(int z = 0; z < 5 ; z++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + known_matrix[s][z]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    Instances testset = filteredInstaces1.stringFreeStructure();

    for(String rm : arrayList)
    {
        int counter =0;
        rm = rm.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]", "");
        Instance testInstance = makeInstance(rm, testset); 
        filter.input(testInstance);

        Instance filteredInstance = filter.output();
        double[] result = tree.distributionForInstance(filteredInstance);

        System.out.print("\n====== RESULT ====== \tCLASSIFIED AS:\t\n");

        int [][] zMatrix = new int[11][5];

        // Threshold code
        for(int c = 0; c < 5;c++)
        {
            if(counter >= count)
                break;

            System.out.print(result[c] + "\t" );

            // Z matrix
            int y = 0;
            max = 0.0;

            if(result[c] >= 0.0 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;
                max = 0.0;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.1 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;
                max = 0.1;                        
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.2 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;
                max = 0.2;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.3 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;
                max = 0.3;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.4 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;
                max = 0.4;
            }     

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.5 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;    
                max = 0.5;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] > 0.6 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;  
                max = 0.6;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.7 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1; 
                max = 0.7;
            }

            y++;

            if(result[c] >= 0.8 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;      
                max = 0.8;
            }                 

            y++;
            if(result[c] >= 0.9 )
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;   
                max = 0.9;
            }                 

            y++;
            if(result[c] == 1.0)
            {
                zMatrix[y][c] = 1;      
                max = 1.0;
            }                    
        }

        counter++;

        System.out.println("\nPredictable matrix\n");
        double v = 0.0;
        for(int g1 = 0; g1 < 11 ; g1++)
        {
            System.out.print(v + "-->" );
            for(int g2=0; g2 < 5; g2++)
            {                        
                System.out.print("\t" + zMatrix[g1][g2]);
            }

            v = t.rounding(v + (0.1));
            System.out.println();
        }
```

I need to do an intersection of known_matrix[][] and zMatrix[][].

Please suggest me a solution. (ignore the bad coding part above, I need to make some changes)

**Input dataset :**

known matrix [][]:

1 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 0 0

zMatrix [][]:

1   1   1   1   1

1   1   0   1   0

1   1   0   1   0

1   0   0   0   0

1   0   0   0   0

1   0   0   0   0

0   1   0   0   0

0   0   1   0   0

0   0   1   0   0

0   1   0   0   0

0   0   1   0   0

Comment: Would you mind giving us some examples of input and output for that input?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, if you are looking for a way to code intersection between 2 arrays, the easiest solution will be to clone one array and for each item in that array -> delete the item if it's not contained in the other array. it might be also better to use lists instead of an array. I'm not even sure this is what you were after, if not, try to explain yourself better.

Comment: how do you intersect or unify on the first array dimension?

ex: `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` and `[ [3,2] ]` , on first dimension, you see 0, 1 as row keys for first array, and only 0 for the the 2nd array's row., does it mean you intersect as: `[ [2] ]` or it means you intersect with equality of the rows, there intersection is null, but `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` and `[ [1,2] ]` would be `[ [1,2] ]`

Comment: Input dataset : (Also edited my main post)

known matrix [][]:

1 1 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 0 0

zMatrix [][]:

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 0 1 0

1 1 0 1 0

1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

Comment: known_matrix is 3 by 5, and zMatrix is 11 by 5? You'll need to specify what you're trying to do better than this.

Comment: here, i'm trying to find the answer for following formula : 
Precision = (Y ∩ Z) / (Y ∪ Z) . In my case Y = known_matrix and Z = zMatrix.

Comment: Honestly, it's much better to write and use a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) than to just post your "bad coding", ask us to ignore it and instead write an example for you. It's too bad because otherwise this question was somewhat interesting.

Comment: I have got the answer..thanks